# What are the flags and macros in a Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to understand structure of a make file but could not understand some macros and flags such as -I is to find header files and -L is for linking to library files, similarly what is  -D , -w ,-s , -f , T1 , TSRC , CFLAG , IDLFLAG ?

Comment: Could you please show the relevant parts of the Makefile?

Comment: Besides, you need to check the documentation on the compiler you are using in order to understand the flags (looks like it is GCC)

Comment: You might use `remake -x` instead of `make` to understand better what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean you "could not understand"? Did you read the documentation?

All of the supported flags are, of course, defined and described [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Some of those that you mention might be compiler and/or flags local to the source code you're trying to build though, it's hard to be more specific without seeing the exact code.

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows me that you are overwhelmed by *both* the structure of a Makefile *and* the options of an average compiler / linker invocation.

As such, there is no way to answer your question in this place, other than suggesting you pick up a "how do use the compiler" tutorial of your choice, and work on that until you are proficient with that (or at least recognize stuff like `-I <include_path>` and `-L <library_path>` at a glance and understand enough to not lump them together with a question about Makefiles).

*Then* pick up a tutorial on Makefiles, and work on that until you are proficient with the technology.

*Then* pick up the Makefile you've just been looking at, again, and ask any specific question that might remain. We will be happy to assist.